# If I forward an attachment in Gmail, does that count toward my storage quota?

Tags: gmail

If I forward an attachment in Gmail, does that count toward my storage quota?

In other words, if I receive a 20 MB attachment and forward it to someone else, does that count as 20 MB or 40 MB in my storage quota?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, if you forward an attachment in Gmail it the attached files count toward your storage quota because forwarding an attachment makes a copy of the original message so you will have the original file and a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, if you forward an attachment with any email services, storage of attached files count toward your storage quota as forwarding an attachments makes a copy of the original message. So there will be two copies, original file and a copy.